# Why Does Neo4j not have bitmap index , B tree index？

Tags: neo4j

I'm learning Neo4j now. And many documents show that we can use schema index and legacy index to optimize querying. And many DB have more kinds of index, such as bitmap index, B tree index. But why does Neo4j not have these kinds of index (such as bitmap B tree)?

I'm very confused. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

Because Neo4j doesn't use indexes for joins just for initial entity lookups (search by value, range, text search)

The actual traversal happens with memory offset pointers which are O(1).

Comment: Got it! Appreciate greatly for you responses.

Comment: I have another question.I have 100GB data to store.  I assume that Neo4j and MySQL have same asocciation rules between data.  Will Neo4j use less storage space  compared to MySQL? Could you please help me ?